# Scipy interpolate 2d error m >= (kx+1)(ky+1) must hold

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to use Scipy interpolate2d option to predict values in points outside of "training" points. I have value=f(b_1,b_2) function which I would like to approximate/interpolate. The matplotlib is able to interpolate using given data and plot it.
[image: Interpolated data]

I tried to use scipy.interpolate.interp2d, but with no success, while executing the error occurs

```
raise TypeError('m >= (kx+1)(ky+1) must hold')
TypeError: m >= (kx+1)(ky+1) must hold
```

and here is the code:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import scipy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

calibration = {'b_1_probe1':    [-2,1.0,2.0,-2.0,1.5,0.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,-0.8,-0.6],
'b_2_probe1':                  [-2,-2.0,0.4,2,1.0,0.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,0.0,0.6,-0.7],
'value':            [5.0,6.0,3.0,4.0,-2.0,3.0,5.0,-3.0,-4.0,1.0,-2.0,3.0],
'value_A_t':            [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,-4.0,-2.0,2.0,-3.0,1.0]}
calibration = pd.DataFrame(calibration,columns= ['b_1_probe1','b_2_probe1','value','second_value'])
x = calibration['b_1_probe1']
y = calibration['b_2_probe1']
z = calibration['value']
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax[0].tripcolor(x,y,z,shading='gouraud')
ax[1].tricontourf(x,y,z, 20) # choose 20 contour levels, just to show how good its interpolation is
ax[1].plot(x,y, 'ko ')
ax[0].plot(x,y, 'ko ')
plt.xlim(-2, 2)
plt.ylim(-2, 2)
plt.show()

# Interpolation goes here
f=scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z, kind='cubic', copy=True, bounds_error=False, fill_value=None)

test = {'b_1':    [-1.8,-0.5,0.4,2,1.0,0.0,1.4,0.6,-1.0,0.0,0.6,-0.7],
        'b_2':    [1.8,1.0,2.0,-1.4,1.5,0.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,-2.0,-0.8,-0.6]}
test = pd.DataFrame(test,columns= ['b_1','b_2'])
xnew = test['b_1']
ynew = test['b_2']
znew = f(xnew, ynew)
plt.plot(x, z[0, :], 'ro-', xnew, znew[0, :], 'b-')
plt.show()
```

I expect that scipy.interpolate will be able to interpolate from given data and show it in plot, so I could compare colour contours before and after interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.

Answer (score 3):

The `TypeError` isn't very clear, but if you dig into the interpolation code you see that `kx = ky = 3` for `cubic` interpolation and `m = len(x)`, so `m >= (kx+1)(ky+1)` isn't true. If you use `kind='linear'` it will work (although there are some other bugs in the code). This is noted in the `interp2d` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp2d).

Comment: So the solution is adding more points, or change `kind` to `'linear'` so `kx=ky=1`